# $f$ and $g$ are two functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ with $f$ strictly increasing .Then.....

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing

$f$ and $g$ are two functions from  $[0,1]$  to  $[0,1]$  with  $f$  strictly increasing .Then  which  of the following is true $?$

$A)$ If $g$ is continuous then so is $f\circ g$

**counterexample :** $g(x)=x$ or $g(x)=1$  and $f(x)={1\over {1-x}}$

$B)$ If $f$ is continuous then so is $f\circ g$

**counterexample :**  $f(x)=x$  and  $g(x)= 
\begin {cases}
 0, & \text{$x$;$x\in \mathbb Q$} \\ 
 1,& \text{$x$;$x\in \mathbb Q^{c}$} \end {cases}$

$C)$ $f$  and  $f\circ g$  is  continuous  then $g$ must be continuous.

$D)$ $g$ and $f\circ g$ is continuous then so is $f.$

**counterexample :** $g(x)={1\over 2}$  and $f(x)={1\over {1-x}}$

So  turns  out  that  the  correct  option  is  **Option $C)$** after  dismissing  all  the rest .But I need  help  to  prove  the  statement  in option $C).$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: $f^{-1}(x)$ exists because $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: $f(x)={1\over {1-x}}$ is not a function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$

Comment: @Henry : So  $2$ of my counter examples  do  not work either !  Can  you suggest  some  slight  modification  of  that  $f$  so  it  could  be made  work $?$